# problems with the UITableView - please advice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have this piece of code and it should bring a ActivityIndicator (thats fine), then go out a query databases twice (looking at the logs it brings in all the correct info). I just STILL does not show up on the tableview and it is driving me crazy!! Can you if possible have a look over the code and see whats wrong - I have been on this for days now - please help!

```
 [super viewDidLoad];
    // create the activity indicator in the main queue
    self.MainTableView.hidden = YES;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *ac = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                   initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [self.view addSubview:ac];
    [ac startAnimating];






    self.client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://outnight-mobile.azure-mobile.net/" applicationKey:@"okYeRGfBagYrsbkaqWIRObeDtktjkF10"];
    self.table = [self.client tableWithName:@"notifications"];
    self.rowitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    MSQuery *query = [self.table query];
    query.fetchLimit = 3;
    [query readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error)
                                {

                                                self.rowitems = [items mutableCopy];
                                                // we have the notifications and the barID in ROWITEMS array
                                                // so lets make this into a dictionary so we can query it
                                                // we need to run this next block of code 3 times, for the 3 bar ids we have got in ROWITEMS
                                                //[self.TableView reloadData];




                                    int a;
                                    for (a = 0; a < 3; a++)
                                    {
                                        NSDictionary *apt = [self.rowitems objectAtIndex:a];
                                        NSLog(@"%@", apt[@"barID"]);
                                        NSDictionary *barIDDictionary = @{ @"myParam": apt[@"barID"]};
                                        self.client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://outnight-mobile.azure-mobile.net/" applicationKey:@"okYeRGfBagYrsbkaqWIRObeDtktjkF10"];
                                        [self.client invokeAPI:@"photos" body:barIDDictionary HTTPMethod:@"POST" parameters:nil headers:nil completion:^(id result, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


                                            if (error) {
                                                        NSLog(@"Error %@", error );
                                            }
                                            else        {
                                                NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [result objectForKey:@"rows"]];
                                                NSString *stringWithoutbracketsend = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
                                                NSString *stringWithoutbracketsfront = [stringWithoutbracketsend stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
                                                NSString *completion = [stringWithoutbracketsfront stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
                                                NSString *newStr = [completion substringFromIndex:1];
                                                NSString *finalstring = [newStr substringToIndex:newStr.length-(newStr.length>0)];
                                                [self.logoURL addObject:finalstring];
                                                NSLog(@"%@",finalstring);
                                             }

                                            }];




                                  }
                                }];

    [self.MainTableView reloadData];
    self.MainTableView.hidden = YES;
}
```

THIS IS ALL MY CODE THANKS

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) MSTable *table;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *items;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *logoURL;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *MainTableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController {
    dispatch_queue_t MyQueue;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // create the activity indicator in the main queue
    self.MainTableView.hidden = YES;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *ac = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                   initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [self.view addSubview:ac];
    [ac startAnimating];






    self.client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://outnight-mobile.azure-mobile.net/" applicationKey:@"okYeRGfBagYrsbkaqWIRObeDtktjkF10"];
    self.table = [self.client tableWithName:@"notifications"];
    self.rowitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    MSQuery *query = [self.table query];
    query.fetchLimit = 3;
    [query readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error)
                                {

                                                self.rowitems = [items mutableCopy];
                                                // we have the notifications and the barID in ROWITEMS array
                                                // so lets make this into a dictionary so we can query it
                                                // we need to run this next block of code 3 times, for the 3 bar ids we have got in ROWITEMS
                                                [self.MainTableView reloadData];




                                    int a;
                                    for (a = 0; a < 3; a++)
                                    {
                                        NSDictionary *apt = [self.rowitems objectAtIndex:a];
                                        NSLog(@"%@", apt[@"barID"]);
                                        NSDictionary *barIDDictionary = @{ @"myParam": apt[@"barID"]};
                                        self.client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://outnight-mobile.azure-mobile.net/" applicationKey:@"okYeRGfBagYrsbkaqWIRObeDtktjkF10"];
                                        [self.client invokeAPI:@"photos" body:barIDDictionary HTTPMethod:@"POST" parameters:nil headers:nil completion:^(id result, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


                                            if (error) {
                                                        NSLog(@"Error %@", error );
                                            }
                                            else        {
                                                NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [result objectForKey:@"rows"]];
                                                NSString *stringWithoutbracketsend = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
                                                NSString *stringWithoutbracketsfront = [stringWithoutbracketsend stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
                                                NSString *completion = [stringWithoutbracketsfront stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
                                                NSString *newStr = [completion substringFromIndex:1];
                                                NSString *finalstring = [newStr substringToIndex:newStr.length-(newStr.length>0)];
                                                [self.logoURL addObject:finalstring];
                                                NSLog(@"%@",finalstring);
                                                [ac stopAnimating];
                                                [self.MainTableView reloadData];
                                                self.MainTableView.hidden = NO;

                                            }

                                            }];




                                  }
                                }];



}














- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    NSDictionary *stress = [self.rowitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = stress[@"content"];






    // putting an image on a row

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.logoURL objectAtIndex:(0)]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]];
            break;
        case 1:
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.logoURL objectAtIndex:(1)]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]];
            break;
        case 2:
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.logoURL objectAtIndex:(2)]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]];
            break;
    }


    return cell;
}



@end
```

Comment: You need to reload the tableview at the end of the completion block, not after the completion block.

Comment: ok I will change it! will let you know! :)

Comment: just done that and its just sitting there with the activity monitor and still no table view, even though i have turned it on as per code.

Comment: I have added some breakpoints in cellForRowAtIndexPath and it doesn't even get there.

Comment: Also make sure you reload the table (and make it visible) on the main thread.

Comment: so your saying do it in the completion block as well as the main thread ?

Comment: the array logoURL has got objects added as my code, but this cannot be seen in my cellForRowAtIndexPath - it is blank.. Is this because it had objects added in a completion block ? If so how do i get around this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to call

```
[self.MainTableView reloadData];
self.MainTableView.hidden = NO;
```

inside `Completion` block

Comment: I have done this, and it just brings back an empty UITextView

Comment: please post bit more code, because is hard to help without seeing full picture

Comment: hi sage, I have attached all my code now at the top, thanks a lot mate. your so helpful

Comment: do you know anyone who would fix this code for payment ? This needs to be done so urgently

Comment: is delegate methods (`-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`) calls?

Comment: I ask because you code looks ok, and should work good. Please tell what you see on screen? Empty table (table with white rows) or nothing ?

Comment: well sage, in cellforRowAtIndexPath I have to comment out the array cos I get an error 'array bounds -0' so it cannot read the array. but besides that its just blank lines.

Comment: I am just completely lost

Comment: oh, replace `return 3;` to `[self.item count];`

Comment: ok, I have done that and HIDDEN=NO after a table reload and the text has come in, I am just a little worried about the images now.

Comment: yes, the images do not work. So I am going to create another question regarding this, but thank you very much for sorting the text out. much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement `UITableViewDatasource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols?

Implement required methods of this 2 protocols and link your `MainTableView`.

Programmatically:

```
MainTableView.datasource = self;
MainTableView.delegate = self;
```

Via storyboard:

[image]

[image]

**UPD:**

Try this code:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
NSDictionary *stress = [self.rowitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [stress objectForKey:@"content"];
```

Comment: I have put this in via the storyboard yes. both delegate and datasource are set.

Comment: @user3307144 could you try put `[MainTableView reloadData]` after 'for' loop?

Comment: really struggling with this now, I am wandering if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your **Query** is running asynchronously. All you need to do is to put your `[tableView reloadData]` in the block that runs after completion of the **Query Block** and make sure that you put the **reloadData** call inside a **dispatch_async** block.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Background work
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update UI
        [tableView reloadData];
    }); });
```